# How to print http header cookies in AEM access.log or request.log?

Tags: apache, logging, aem, aem-6

For a debugging purpose, I want to print a specific cookie value in my access.log or request.log. 
One way to do is, from the dispatcherServlet, add a logger for SlingHttpRequest.getCookies(). But this debugging is needed in Production and I cant make java code changes and deploy.

I read the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) and tried to change the `org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern` property in `org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config` in the configManager for access.log like this:

`{0,date,dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} *{4}* [{2}] {3} {5} "%cookie{login-token}"`

This didnt help. Able to see date timestamp changed, {2} {3} etc are printing. But as desired, the cookie value is not printing.

How to print the cookie values in http headers in AEM log files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the entire documentation that you are referring to is supported OOB. The pattern format in AEM specifically points to the [Pattern Layout](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) section of the documentation. As part of that, there is no support for request cookies.

The request cookies section is specifically present under the pattern layout of the **Logback access** section which states the below

> PatternLayout in logback-access can be configured in much the same way
>   as its classic counterpart. However it features additional conversion
>   specifiers suited for logging particular bits of information available
>   only in HTTP servlet requests and HTTP servlet responses.

That being said, the [sling logging documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/logging.html#slf4j-mdc) mentions using a Sling extension for slf4j MDC support which can be used to expose some of the request variables including cookies. Extract from the doco below

> The filter allows configuration to extract data from request cookie,
>   header and parameters. Look for configuration with name 'Apache Sling
>   Logging MDC Inserting Filter' for details on specifying header,
>   cookie, param names.

[image]

Once the MDC bundle is [downloaded](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sling/org.apache.sling.extensions.slf4j.mdc/1.0.0/org.apache.sling.extensions.slf4j.mdc-1.0.0.jar) and added to your instance, you can use the log back patterns instead of the classic pattern for the log format. Example from the doco shown below.

```
%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} *%p* [%X{req.remoteHost}] [%t] %c %msg%n
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @rakhi4110. So I installed the MDC bundle, configured the cookies, but still trying to figure the right log pattern to print. Right now it is printing only the default values. Will close this once I figure the right log pattern.

Comment: As per the provided documentation, you should be able to access the cookie header with `%X{req.cookie}` in your logging pattern, after adding that header to the Apache Sling Logging MDC Inserting Filter configuration.  I doubt you'll be able to access a specific cookie with this approach, since it will add the entire cookie header.

Comment: @rakhi4110 what's with the weird mirror for the MDC bundle?  (My guess is it came from the Sling documentation's download page for that bundle.)  Why not link to the jar in the maven central repo?  I validated the md5 checksum, and confirmed it's the legitimate file, but it's a lot easier to trust Maven Central.  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sling/org.apache.sling.extensions.slf4j.mdc/1.0.0/org.apache.sling.extensions.slf4j.mdc-1.0.0.jar